# How to set item renderer for ListView in ext-gwt?

Tags: gwt, listview, itemrenderer, gxt

I have a `ListView` in ext-gwt and I'm adding some custom data to it.  How can I set an item renderer on the `ListView`?  As of right now, whenever an item is added, there's just a small line representing each entry in the view.

Here's my basic code:

```
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.ListView;
import com.foo.bar.FooModelData;


private final ListStore<FooModelData> listStore = 
    new ListStore<FooModelData>();
private final ListView<FooModelData> listView = 
    new ListView<FooModelData>();

public initializeView()
{
    listView.setStore(listStore);
    listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
}

public void addItem(FooModelData data) {
    listStore.add(data);
}


public class FooModelData extends BaseModel
{
    public ModelDataInstance(Foo foo, String style)
    {
        setFoo(foo);
        setStyle(style);
    }

    public String getStyle()
    {
        return get("style");
    }

    public Foo getFoo()
    {
        return (Foo) get("foo");
    }

    public void setStyle(String style)
    {
        set("style", style);
    }

    public void setFoo(Foo foo)
    {
        set("foo", foo);
    }

}
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GXT uses a templating implementation.
Using a simplified version of the Sencha explorer example you could use your data as follows (foo.name assumes foo is also a model:

```
public initializeView()
{
listView.setStore(listStore);
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
listView.setTemplate(getTemplate());
}

private native String getTemplate() /*-{ 
 return ['<tpl for=".">',
 '<div class="{style}">{foo.name}</div>', 
 '</tpl>', 
 '<div class="x-clear"></div>'].join(""); 
}-*/;
```